# Firebase auth.onAuthStateChanged data isn't persistent in expo react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to keep a user signed in after restarting the app but whenever the app restarts the state is empty & there is no user.

I have couldn't find any solution for this.

This is the splash screen I am checking for `auth.onAuthStateChanged`.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      } else {
        navigation.replace("Login");
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>SplashScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

This is my `firebase.js` file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  //config here
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db,app}
```

this is my package.json if you want to know about the version:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am new to react native so I am a bit confused why this is happening and I can't find any solution for this. I tried to use `setInterval` to give onAuthStateChanged time to get the user but it doesn't work.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue and I would be very grateful!

Edit:
I have also used this :

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
```